# What is wrong with the syntax with line 7 in my code? It says my print statement has invalid syntax and I can't figure it out?

Tags: python, printing, syntax, syntax-error

```
total_cost_of_food = float(input('How much did the food cost? '))
sales_tax = 8.25
tax_plus_total = total_cost_of_food * sales_tax / 100 
print("Your tax for this meal was:", tax_plus_total)
x = bool(input("Would you like to add a tip? ")
    if x is False
        print("Thanks, your total for today is:", tax_plus_total)
    else
        print("That is", x, "I would like to add a tip")
```

I keep getting this error for my print statement that is under the if statement, it says it's a syntax error but I don't see anything wrong with the syntax... I have only been coding for about a week though so I am likely missing something.

Comment: Why is `if x is False` indented?  It belongs at the same level of indent as the rest of the code.

Comment: Could you please share error message?

Comment: ```print("Thanks, your total for today is:", tax_plus_total)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include that, with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The `:` is missing, at the end of the `if` line and the `else` line

Instead of `if x is False`, you should use `if not x:`

Also, you should reduce the indenting of all four lines in your `if-else` construct, by one level.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but after I added the ```:``` to my code after the ```if``` and ```else``` lines it gave me a syntax error for the semicolon. Again, sorry if this is a dumb question, I am very new at this.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Even better: use `if x:` (to avoid negatives) and swap the two `print` statements.

Comment: @DrewStapp: That's because you have *another* syntax error on the line before *that* - you forgot a closing parenthesis. Remember to check for that in the future - it'll happen a lot. (Also `:` is a colon, not a semicolon. `;` is a semicolon.)

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much I can’t believe I missed that. I really appreciate it omg thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`bool(input("Would you like to add a tip? ")` lacks the second closing parenthesis.

Python very often prints a syntax error for the next line or even a subsequent line after that when you have a missing closing parenthesis. It tries to make sense of what you wrote and it takes a while for it to figure out that it really can't.

This also masks the indentation error on the following line, and the lack of a colon at the end of the `if` and `else` lines.